# Zend_Db performances

Tags: php, performance, zend-db

After doing some research on differents libraries/framework to implement in a pretty big application (350 tables db, several millions entries on some tables) I found out that Zend_Db do pretty easily what I want to do: Adapter management for quick switch between databases.

The problem is that performances are really low, here's an example (**$db** is a basic adapter, the time is computed on the select/fetch only) :

**SQL QUERY** (the query used for testing, the table contains ~200 elements)

```
SELECT * FROM element WHERE id=2'
```

**Basic PDO - 0.6392s**

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=etab_191;host=127.0.0.1', 'root');
for ($i=0; $i<2000; $i++) {
    $stmt = $db->query($sql);
    $p = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $stmt->closeCursor();
}
```

**Current Application database manager - 0.7401s** (simple abstraction layer over mysqli core functions)

```
$db = GestionConnexionBDD::getInstance('default', 1)->gestionBDD;
for ($i=0; $i<2000; $i++) {
    $res = $db->query($sql);
    $p = $db->fetchObject($res);
    $db->freeResult($res);
}
```

**Zend_Db manual query - 1.0647s** (Mv_Core_Db_Manager is an abstraction layer based on Zend, returning a list of Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract)

```
    $db = Mv_Core_Db_Manager::getInstance()->getAdapter('default', 1);
for ($i=0; $i<2000; $i++) {
    $stmt = $db->query($sql);
    $p = $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->closeCursor();
}
```

**Zend_Db_Table_Abstract query - 3.6702s** (tweaked with Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultMetadataCache($cache))

```
$elmt = new Element();
for ($i=0; $i<2000; $i++) {
    $elmt->find(2);
}
```

Querying on a loop kills zend performances. I know it's not the best thing to do, but the application is already developed and i'd love to change less code possible.

Some ideas ? Am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: I think you have an error in your example code for Zend_Db_Table_Abstract: `$db->fetchAll($sql);` doesn't fit in.

Comment: thanks, I changed that to fetchOne()

Comment: still, I wonder why you execute both a find() on the Zend_Db_Table_Abstract Class and a fetch operation on the Zend_Db_Adapter class ;)

Comment: awwwn my bad, I miscopied my example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend_DB_Abstract will query table metadata on each PHP request.

This means doing a DB DESCRIBE TABLE, that can be very slow on some databases.

To avoid this, you can cache such metadata, and this will improve query performance:

```
    /////////////////////////////
    // getting a Zend_Cache_Core object
    $cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core',
        'File',
        array('lifetime' => 86400, 'automatic_serialization' => true ),
        array('cache_dir' => $config->cacheDir));

    // Next, set the cache to be used with all table objects
    Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultMetadataCache($cache);
```

Comment: this can actually save 1 - 2 seconds with an oracle db !

Answer (score 1):

Abstraction has a price.

Zend is a php framework, which is of curse much slower than native extensions like pdo.
Zend_DB / Zend_Db_Table creates lot of instances of classes at runtime.
maybe you run you app much fast with a bytecodecache like apc or that build-in in zend-server.

maybe [HipHop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/) is also a solution for you.

Comment: That's a fact, but i'd love to know if I'm doing something wrong too before abadoning the solution for a more simple approach. I have to say that I were surprised by the low performances on multiple queries, but maybe Zend isn't make to do things like thoses.

Comment: Zend Framework is just another layer that does create, parse and make class objects out of stuff instead of just passing an array.  I wouldn't be surprised if in such large DB structures ZDB adds significant overhead.  The only thing I can think of is that Zend Server is supposed to be able to work well with Zend Framework and compile code for optimization and performance.  I've never tried it though.

Answer (score 1):

A few pointer:

- using Table / Row classes will always be slightly slower because of the added overhead of the objectification (if that is even a word ;) )
- at my workplace we just had similar problems using doctrine (1.2), in the next few weeks we'll be experimenting with [APC](http://devzone.zend.com/1812/using-apc-with-php/) (sadly, the images on that article are gone)
- I thought Zend_Db had a query cache mechanism, but I can't find informations about it in the reference guide

Comment: I'm a frequent Zend Framework (ZF) user, though none of my applications are intense enough to have done strict performance assessments.   ZF uses Zend_Cache to allow you to cache anything.  What you would do is basically take your query results, and have Zend_Cache cache them using some unique identifiable index.  In the above example, their query is "WHERE id=2", so the index could just be "2" or "id2" or whatever.  Then, before you hit the database, you check Zend_Cache with a simple IF(hasCache('id2')) like statement and pull the cache and not requery the DB.

Comment: unfortunately that's not a solution for the application, data just keep changing (multi-user application) and storing query result into cache isn't the solution, but I thought that maybe Zend could prepare the query in some way and then just change the identifier with the placeholder '?'

Comment: Of course, Caching is only valuable if the values aren't frequently changing and you'll have to clear the cache if a value does change.  Given the context of what we're talking about this is usually done as a web app. with some sort of admin CMS-like backend where you add-edit-delete items from a database.  You can then tie in a cache clear into the add-edit-delete functions. *edit* opps, kitensei just confirmed cache won't work.

Comment: @kitensei: that was the mechanism I was looking for. doctrine has such a cache, maybe I was mixing the two up...sadly, can't recomend doctrine for speed, it seems to be even slower - at least in 1.2, not sure about the 2.x versions